# Multiple Android App in single Google Firestore Project

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I presently work on Firestore project in Android. The project works perfectly. Now I want to create another android app for the same Firestore project. This is a helping tool for the main app.
But here I try to add another app to Firestore it displays error the same SHA key is used.
Now how to rectify this problem?

Comment: Have you add it via the toolbar on left in project settings add app?

Comment: You need a different goodle-services.json for different app

Comment: when adding another android app to your firebase project ,you need not to add again SHA key. Just create/add another app, and now your firebase project will update the google-services.json file copy this file to both projects and your both apps should work well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add another app to a Firebase project, you need to do at least one of two things:

1. Give the app a new application ID
2. Sign the app with a different signing key (different SHA-1)

If you want to use the same signing key for the second app, then you will have to give the app a different application ID than the first.